# How can I define something similar to a structure in NetLogo?

Tags: list, object, structure, netlogo

I defined a lot of "object" like this:
[image]

Each of them has properties, like color, size, position ecc.

How can I store them in a list and assign to them a unique identifier?

I make them as follow:

```
let tmploop 0
while [tmploop < 20] [
    makecell tmploop
    set tmploop tmploop + 1
]

to makecell [ n ]
    let head random 360
    let jum random 20
    create-turtles n
        [ set shape "circle"
        set color green
        set size 2
        set heading head
        jump jum]
    create-turtles n
        [ set shape "circle"
        set color red
        set size 1.33
        set heading head
        jump jum]
    create-turtles n
        [ set shape "circle"
        set color gray
        set size 0.66
        set heading head
        jump jum]
end
```

I would like to refer to each ring of the same cell, for example.

Should I use something like `breed` or do you have other ideas?

Comment: If by "structure" you mean something like a C struct, where you can store varied data by name, NetLogo agents already provide this.  If you are looking for a non-agent object where you can store information by name, use the `table` extension.

Comment: @Alan I would like something like:
struct cell {
 struct turtle1 {

 },
 struct turtle2 {

 },
 struct turtle3 {

 }
}
What do you suggest to use?

Comment: @Alan I think that using the agents in some way is better:
can you provide me an example, using my structure?

Comment: The question isn't clear. I don't get what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SethTisue I would like to define an object (cell) formed by three part (rings) that has different parameters.
I would like to be able to refer at them to change some of their parameters.
I would like the following hierarchy: struct cell [ struct ring1 [par1,par2], struct ring2 [par1,par2], struct ring3 [par1,par2]]

Comment: Like Seth, I'm not fully understanding your goals.  But, would this work?  Have `cell` and `ring` breeds.  Each cell can have a directed link to each of its rings.  Using `rings-own`, you can (mutably) store any information you wish in the rings.

Comment: I like Alan's suggestion.

Comment: @Alan can you give me a code example of that?

Comment: I can't define well links

Comment: @Ale1794 ask a new question and include code with your best attempt at doing this with links, and explain where you got stuck. we can help you improve it from there.